# Value not populated in the textbox

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a textbox with id Name.
View:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6 control-label">
                     @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "" })
                    <i class="required">*</i>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", autocomplete = "off" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
```

and in the developer tool:

However the Textbox doesn't contain any value. and it is blank.

Can anyone find what I am missing? I have also tried using ModelState.Clear().

Comment: Are you passing the model to the view from the controller ?

Comment: yes. and In the view I added the watch-  the value of Model- Name - contains the value as org1